# Struts2 Action called twice

Tags: java, struts2

I am calling struts action like

```
<a href="someactionLink.action">Do action</a>
```

In Struts.xml

```
<action name="*Link" method="{1}" class="com.shashi.getalldata.LinkAction">
```

The problem is the action called twice. Once when i click the href and second time while page loading.  Do any one have any idea on what's the case here?

Comment: Resource interpreted as image but transferred with MIME type text/html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have anything on the page that could result in a subsequent request?  E.g.  favicon/stylesheet/image/script.  By favicon, I mean lack of, but the browser might be looking (most browsers only look in one place for them).

Check the access logs for a subsequent request.

Comment: Thank your for your reply.
As you told this only happens in chrome. I get the following warning
Resource interpreted as image but transferred with MIME type text/html  someactionLink.action

But in IE it works fine

Any idea????

Comment: @Shashi I think you could try hosting a favicon so the browser can cache it and stop looking for one in unusual places.

Comment: Hi I am also getting the same issue. I have a struts 2 Hibernate app. It works fine on local system but on server sometimes forms are submitted twice. This happens very rarely on server. At local end it never happens. This results in duplicate data being submitted in database. What could be the reason for such double submission of forms? We have used javascript and normal button to submit form and sometimes struts 2 submit button. In both cases sometimes form is submitted twice. Only sometimes. Even if the form has only one field and there is not much processing. Just Save.

Comment: @Ashish: Form submission is very different.  The most likely culprit is the user, double-clicking instead of single-clicking if the submissions are very close together in the logs.  If they are slightly further apart, then it's more likely to be the user being impatient and clicking again or refreshing the page.  If they are really far apart, it's more likely that the user is using their browsing history and has resubmitted the data that way.  In ALL cases, server-side code to detect and prevent duplicate submissions is the only answer (e.g. Optimistic Locking).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this link. It helped me figure out my issue with a double submit. It had nothing to do with my code, it was completely YSlow plug-in for FireFox 3.X and 4.X.

[Double submit solution](http://struts.1045723.n5.nabble.com/Struts-2-actions-executing-twice-td3486428.html)

Answer (score 0):

Solution to my double submit issue.

first off: I was doing a form submit using javascript. Like:

```
<a href="#" onclick="save();">
      <input type="image" src="images/save.gif" alt="Save" title="Save" /></a>
```

where save() was:

```
function save() {
     ...
     document.form_name.action = "Struts2_action.action";
     document.forms[1].submit(); 
   }
```

Well I was NOT adding "return false;" after save() to do the following:

Return false follow three steps

- First It stops the browsers default behaviour.
- It prevents the event from propagating the DOM
- Stops callback execution and returns immediately when called.

So, my anchor became:

```
<a href="#" onclick="save();return false;">
          <input type="image" src="images/save.gif" alt="Save" title="Save" /></a>
```

and the double submit problem was resolved.

Comment: Hi, my case doesn't work only add "return false;" to onClick, I'm looking for other alternative. That problem is in google chrome but in firefox work fine.